# Django forms field parameters passed from view

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a simple form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
```

Every user in my app has variable stored in session called 'my_amount'. I would like to pass this variable (or session, or request) to form from my class based FormView.

I found i should do this like this:

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(MyFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        kwargs['my_amount'] = self.request.session.get('my_amount')
        return kwargs
```

I modified my form this way:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.my_amount = kwargs.pop('my_amount')
        return super(MyForm, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)

    my_field = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=self.my_amount)
```

But Django shows error that "self" in max_value=self.my_amount is not recognized. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the last line of code you posted:

```
my_field = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=self.my_amount)
```

Python (not django) can't parse that because there is no "self" in scope at that line. You're defining a class-scope identifier there.

However, that doesn't answer the larger question of how to make your code achieve its purpose. I don't follow what you're trying to do, keeping the variable in session and then a form, but at a glance the code looks complicated for such a simple intention. Perhaps clarify the objective more, possibly asking in a separate question if still having trouble?

EDIT

Based on your comment, I made a small demo. The HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Your balance is <strong>{{balance}}</strong>.</p>
<form method='POST'>
  <input name='key' type='text' placeholder="Enter 'good', 'great' or 'bad' for a result">
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value="Go">
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

The view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    # ensure initial balance
    balance = request.session.get('balance', 0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        key = request.POST.get('key')
        if key == 'good':
            balance += 10

        elif key == 'great':
            balance += 50

        elif key == 'bad':
            balance -= 5

    # Persist the balance in the session
    request.session['balance']=balance

    # You could omit these two lines but by redirecting back to the 'GET'
    # form you don't have to worry about "resubmitting the form" warnings.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(request.path)

    return render(request, 'nov17/index.html', dict(balance=balance))
```

The first time you load the page it will show:

```
Your balance is 0.
[text input] [Go]
```

If you type 'good' in the input and press the button, 10 points are added. Type 'great' and 50 points are added, etc.

This is a toy, of course, but it proves that modifying a session variable based on an action is very simple.

I didn't follow the part about "I want users to be able to post number in my_field not greater than my_amount stored in session" but I think that's a separate question.

Comment: Every user in my app is able to achieve points for actions on my website. I store how many points he gets in session variable 'my_amount' for his convenience, to let him do this without first creating account. Then after user gain as many points as he needs, he can register/log in and use MyForm to spend some part of this points to redeem prize (specified by other field in MyForm, that I didn't describe here because is irrelevant for the problem). I want users to be able to post number in my_field not greater than my_amount stored in session.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I described my problem not clear enough. I don't need to code view that will store something in session, this is already done. I need to build Django form based on this variable stored in session. Precisely, I need to use this session variable as 'max_value' argument for IntegerField. I would like to use Form from django.forms module to avoid repeating code. And I would like to use Class-based views, because it seems to be the direction Django is moving.

Comment: The max value on a form field is set at startup, not at runtime on a per call basis. If all you want to do is validate that the incoming number is less than the session number then look into custom form validaton logic. As a side note, I'm not saying to use function based views, it was a toy application to prove you don't need the FormView etc to process post parameters in a simple fashion. You could simply get the value, compare it to the session variable and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found answer to my question. As Andrew E. stated in comment, forms fields are set up during first process, not every time form is called. But form class **init**(self) method is called every time. So I could create it this way:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        my_amount = kwargs.pop('my_amount')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_field'].max_value = my_amount
```

Now my_field is set up at start, but it is initialized every time with max_value argument passed from view. Seems to be working for now.